# Setting one CSV as an array to compare data from another CSV

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, csv, printing, compare

I am new to Python and am over complicating the coding on a project so I am starting with much smaller data sets in order to learn the process. My boss is having me compare two CSV files. The first CSV only contains the data 1,2,3,4,5,6 all in a single column. He wants me to set this CSV file as an array so I can compare the second CSV against it. The second CSV contains the data 3,5,6 all in a single column. The code should result in a print out of 1,2,4 as it is the only data not found in both CSV files.

I originally tried to write a code to import both CSV files and compare data without setting it as an array but this did not work so the first CSV file needs to be set as an array. The problem is I am not sure exactly how to do this with an array. This is what I have so far, any help anyone could give me would be greatly appreciated. I have been working on this project for a week now and am at a total loss, even with this simplified form.

```
import csv
temp_list = []
with open('1.csv','rb') as csvfile: 

    reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',') 
    for row in reader:
```

Answer (score 0):

In terms of psuedo-code, what you need to do here is import both csv files into two separate arrays, Array A and Array B for example.

Now what you need to do is compare each index position in one array, to each index position in the other array.
You need to create a nested loop, where the outer loop will choose an index position in A and then inner loop chooses a position in B.

After you check one index in A with each position in B, and no positions are the same, I suggest adding this value into a third array, C. You can check which positions are the same by using a boolean flag. When your code is done, C will have any values that don't exist in both A and B.

I suggest following these tutorials to learn more about python syntax:
https://www.w3schools.com/python/

Good luck